# Laravel Blade: use $variable or 'xxx' inside asset()

Tags: laravel, assets, laravel-blade, conditional-operator

I want to change the logo in my header on certain pages.
I'm therefore extending my layout like this:

`@extends('templates.main', ['logo' => 'img/logo/logo_red_white_text.png'])`

In my layout when no `$logo` isset it uses the default one:

`<img src="{{ asset($logo or 'img/logo/logo_yellow_white_text.png') }}" alt="">`

However this doesn't work. It only works when I remove `asset()` but then the logo will not be shown when using a prefix (for example app.dev/en/mypage), so I need asset.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<img src="{{ asset(isset($logo) ? $logo : 'img/logo/logo_yellow_white_text.png') }}" alt="">
```

Unfortunetelly you can use `or` laravel's blade statment only for echoing like this:

```
{{$logo or 'img/logo/logo_yellow_white_text.png'}}
```